# ReactDom is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-dom

I am using React with Webpack and Babel. I am getting a runtime error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDom is not defined

My react version is:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
   "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.8"
 },    
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^0.14.7",
   "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
 },
```

and my code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './components/main';

ReactDom.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have `ReactDOM` but you don't have `ReactDom`*(case sensitive)*

```
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: you're a Legend :)

Comment: So what's the difference then?

Answer (score 4):

`ReactDOM` **!=** `ReactDom`. There are two things you can do to fix this.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; // you used 'react-dom' as 'ReactDOM'
import Main from './components/main';

ReactDom.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root')); // you referred to it as 'ReactDom' which is wrong.
```

Becasue `ReactDOM` != `ReactDom`. So you need to fix one of those places so that both places have the same name with the same case.

The recommended fix would be,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; // this is recommended 
import Main from './components/main';

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Or you can do,

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Main from './components/main';

ReactDom.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor error in your code you have written ReactDom instead of ReactDOM.
The correct code should be given below :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './components/main';

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```